# Revtex 4.1 multiple affiliations

Tags: titles, revtex, affiliation

**EDITED:11-23-2010**
In case anyone stumbles upon this question and has a similar problem. The Ubuntu/Debian repositories have an old version of revtex that exhibit this bug. Until the repos are updated, there is a .deb file available in the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-extra/+bug/575812?comments=all) that installs the new version of revtex

**--**

I'm Trying to get multiple affiliations for the author list when using revtex-4.1

The default behavior is to group the authors together according to affiliation as so:

[image]

However, this requires you to group authors together in an unnatural way, and usually in a way that conflicts with authorship politics. Even if you switch to superscriptaddress mode, the requirement on grouping still remains.

For example, If I want to have two authors share an affiliation, but have one of the authors have a second affiliation, the whole thing ends up ignoring the first affiliation of the second author: e.g.

```
\author{J. T. Ripper}
\affiliation{Bethlem Royal Psychiatric Hospital}
\author{Bugs Bunny}
\affiliation{Looney Tunes}
\author{Daffy Duck}
\affiliation{Looney Tunes}
\affiliation{Warner Brothers}
```

Gives you the following

[image]

If you try to remove bug's affiliation then they both end up inheriting both affiliations. Like so:

```
\author{J. T. Ripper}
\affiliation{Bethlem Royal Psychiatric Hospital}
\author{Bugs Bunny}
\author{Daffy Duck}
\affiliation{Looney Tunes}
\affiliation{Warner Brothers}
```

[image]

What I want it to do is to give Daffy two superscripts, and Bugs bunny only one. The picture gets even harrier if (for example) I try to put J Ripper in between bugs and daffy. Then the numbers get even more screwed up.  Using alt affiliations doesn't solve the problem because the alt affilliation goes into a footnote.

There used to be a "feature" in revtex-4, that if you used `\address` instead of `\affiliation` , then the whole thing behaves as expected. However, it seems that the latest version of revtex4-1, has patched this "bug", and now even old documents that worked fine, have broken affiliations. e.g.:

With Revtex 4:

[image]

With Revtex 4-1:

[image]

Ignore the style differences (the first one was typeset by arxiv with a prl instead of an api style).The latex behind the two is identical. 
Full Disclosure: I'm one of the twenty co-authors

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Works for me. I am using

```
Document Class: revtex4-1 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r
```

which fixes a number of bugs in the affiliation code.

Testcase:

```
\documentclass[superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
\author{J. T. Ripper}
\affiliation{Bethlem Royal Psychiatric Hospital}
\author{Bugs Bunny}
\affiliation{Looney Tunes}
\author{Daffy Duck}
\affiliation{Looney Tunes}
\affiliation{Warner Brothers}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Result: [image]

Comment: Well This makes me feel stupid. Both Debian and Ubuntu had an old version in their repos. And I thought it wasn't the package because the systems are maintained by different people *sigh*. Anyway, thanks a bunch, I had to hack in the new revtex and I'm off to go bug canonical.

Answer (score 5):

This can be accomplished by selecting the class option `superscriptaddress` in documentclass.

```
\documentclass[
reprint,
superscriptaddress,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
pra,
]{revtex4-2}
```