# Removing "And" in Revtex 4.1 author list

Tags: titles, revtex

I am submitting an abstract using a LaTeX template. The template makes use of RevTex 4.1 and it includes an example abstract. In this example, the numbers that show the author affiliation are hard-coded (presumably to show how to deal with the [affiliation mess](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5805/revtex-4-1-multiple-affiliations) that can arise for more complex author lists):

```
\documentclass[aps,12pt]{revtex4}
\begin{document}
\title{Why Some Dogs Talk and Others Don't}
\author{\underline{B.~Bunny}$^1$, and
        M.~Mouse$^2$}
\affiliation{$^1$Looney Tune Studios}
\affiliation{$^2$Disney Inc.}

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}
```

The problem is that this leads to a misplaced "and" between the affiliation descriptions:

[image]

How can I modify the code so that this "and" disappears? My author-list actually is quite complex, and I would like to hard-code the numbers as shown here, so that my one-page limit is not blown by the affiliation list.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: How can I improve my post? I tried to get the formatting right, removed all greetings and "thanks in advance", and included a compilable example. Did I miss something?

Comment: Absolutely no :) The link I provided is a welcome page which contains helpful tricks and guidelines that might help you.

Comment: Ahh, I see that I missed that the answer was already here. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48407/removing-the-and-from-between-two-authors-revtex4-1?rq=1  I just did not find it in my previous searches. I compiled an example with the solution and made a nice picture, but I guess I cannot answer my own question for another 8 hours... Maybe this question should be closed, then...